# External HDD. Very slim. Max 10 mm. 1-2 TB

Tags: hard-disk

I have found Seagate Backup Plus Ultra Slim 1TB but there are enough users reported about the bad experience. After some weeks it doesn't work anymore.

Max 10 mm because I want it to use this external HDD with my notebook and transport it together in the same bag.

It it for a MacBook Pro 13 from 2015. I prefer USB 3.0, but could accept Thunderbolt 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Seagate Backup Plus Slim 1TB Portable External Hard Drive for Mac USB 3.0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00H4YGR48) Seems to meet your requirements. Its slim, coming in at  9.6mm tall.

I tried finding an SSD solution for you, but nothing would fit in that form factor. If your willing to settle on 512GB, I would recommend the [AngleBird SSD2go](http://www.angelbird.com/en/prod/ssd2go-pkt-1031/#overview), it is smaller... and substantially faster than any HDD.

The Seagate drive is a USB 3.0, and the Anglefire is USB 3.1 Gen2 10Gbit/s.
These are my suggestions, I hope they help.

Comment: I'm always weary when looking at a 1 star review for any tech. I'm assuming people might be buying these for consoles and is disappointed with the speed (console is usb 2.0). Just the way I look at reviews I guess. My oldest drives, 3 2tb seagate drives have been under heavy load for almost 8 years now. They hold actively seeded torrents on a computer that is on 24/7. My newest WD drive is 6tb and failed after 3 months. So I guess it is kind of a lottery draw.

Comment: @BigElittles Xbox one has USB 3.0 for drives so :P, but yes, a lot of people will buy drives for *insert device*, only to figure out that they will not get the same transfer speeds as if they were installed say, using eSATA or SATA III connections, therefore they give negative reviews saying the drives are at fault, when in fact it is the connection interface that is to blame.